# В чем различия Wi-Fi модулей ESP32 и ESP8266?

Tags: wifi

В чем заключаются принципиальные различия между ESP32 и ESP8266? Просто новая и старая модель? Характеристики? Может ли плата Wi-Fi модуля продолжать также работать если заменить в ней ESP32 на ESP8266 или что-то измениться, или вообще работать не будет?

Answer (score 0):

Разный обьем памяти, немного разные частоты процессора, щиток металический. Будет работать или нет - зависит от программы. Простые программы должны запуститься